# weakly-referenced object no longer exists using python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a local database which i try to  update using python the following code is what i used

```
>>> from mysql.connector import connect
>>> p = connect(user="root", password="", host="127.0.0.1", port="3306", database='ef')
>>> cur = p.cursor()
>>> p = "s"
>>> cur.execute("""update ef_reg set region_status = %s where region_id=851""",(p))
```

When i run the last one i get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 473, in execute
    if not self._connection:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `,` after `p`. And also you need to change the connection object's name.

```
K = connect(user="root", password="", host="127.0.0.1", port="3306", database='ef')
cur = k.cursor()
p = "s"
cur.execute("""update ef_reg set region_status = %s where region_id=851""",(p,))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do the following -

```
p = "s"
```

That makes the name `p` reference a new string `"s"` , and it loses the old reference to the connection object.

And after that the only reference to the connection object is the weak reference in the cursor object. So according to [documentation of weak references](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) -

> A weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive: when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its memory for something else.

After that most probably python is garbage collecting the connection object since it does not have any reference in the script (And the reference held. But when you are trying to execute the script, it again tries to use the now garbage collected connection object, causing the issue that the connection object no longer exists.

Try using a different name for the string , maybe `s` or so.

Example to show the garbage collection behavior -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __del__(self):
...             print("CA Deleted")
...
>>> c = CA()
>>> c = "s"
CA Deleted
```